# R plot: Draw text always at the same absolute distance relative to plot

Tags: r, plot

I have the following problem. I have a bit a complex barplot where I want to add descriptions on the right hand side of the chart. My idea was to basically increase the margin on the right (mar) to 15.0 and draw the text directly next to the graph. This works most of the time but if I increase the size of my plot window the text is drawn too much outside of the plot region since the x position is "relative". Is there any way to fix this? Because now my x position is defined by this:
max(ReturnMatrix)+0.005
And of course depending on the width of the graph this shifts the text to far out...

Here is my sample code (I use it in Shiny and the error occurs if a resize the browser window for example)

```
ReturnMatrix<-matrix(c(0.024, 0.007, 0.006, 0.001, -0.001, -0.002, -0.0011))
    row.names(ReturnMatrix)<-c("Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5", "Test6", "Test7")

    par(bg=rgb(199/255,228/255,246/255), mar=c(0,4,0,15.0))



    bp<- barplot(ReturnMatrix, 
            beside=TRUE, 
            horiz=TRUE, 
            axes=FALSE,
            space=3,
            col=ifelse(ReturnMatrix>0,"green","red"))

    text(ReturnMatrix,bp,signif(ReturnMatrix,1),pos=ifelse(ReturnMatrix>0,4,2), xpd=TRUE)
    text(rep(max(ReturnMatrix)+0.005,7),bp,row.names(ReturnMatrix), xpd=TRUE, pos=4)
    abline(v=0)
    bp
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe extend plot area to include text?

```
ReturnMatrix<-matrix(c(0.024, 0.007, 0.006, 0.001, -0.001, -0.002, -0.0011))
row.names(ReturnMatrix)<-c("Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5", "Test6", "Test7")
space=3
plot(0,0,type="n",xlim=c(min(ReturnMatrix),1.5*max(ReturnMatrix)),ylim=c(0,(space+1)*length(ReturnMatrix)),axes="off")
bp<- barplot(ReturnMatrix, 
        beside=TRUE, 
        horiz=TRUE, 
        axes=FALSE,
        space=space,
        add=TRUE,
        col=ifelse(ReturnMatrix>0,"green","red")
)
text(ReturnMatrix,bp,signif(ReturnMatrix,1),pos=ifelse(ReturnMatrix>0,4,2), xpd=TRUE)
text(rep(1.25*max(ReturnMatrix),7),bp,row.names(ReturnMatrix), xpd=TRUE, pos=4)
# changed position to 1.25*max bar
abline(v=0)
```